# Why will QGIS only import the first 20 lines of my delimited text file?

Tags: qgis

I have a file of bird species and counts with Lat Long that I want to put into QGIS (2.0). However, when I add the file it only shows the first 20 entries (excluding the field titles). This is the same whether I type the file out by hand from scratch, save it in different formats, export a working attribute table from ArcMap etc... Its even done the same thing with a separate CSV file...

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Alex

[image: Example of imported file]

This is a sample of the data:

```
S_ID,S_NAME,COUNT,DATE,OBSERVER,LOCATION,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
1,Mallard,6,27-Apr-14,Douglas_Philp,"Ely_Trail,_Pontyclun,_Rhondda,_Cynon,_Taff_County",-3.408753487,51.54959248
2,Grey_Heron,1,27-Apr-14,Douglas_Philp,"Ely_Trail,_Pontyclun,_Rhondda,_Cynon,_Taff_County",-3.408753487,51.54959248
3,White-throated_Dipper,1,27-Apr-14,Douglas_Philp,"Ely_Trail,_Pontyclun,_Rhondda,_Cynon,_Taff_County",-3.408753487,51.54959248
4,Grey_Wagtail,1,27-Apr-14,Douglas_Philp,"Ely_Trail,_Pontyclun,_Rhondda,_Cynon,_Taff_County",-3.408753487,51.54959248
5,Canada_Goose,5,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
6,Ring-necked_Pheasant,2,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
7,Manx_Shearwater,1,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
8,Northern_Gannet,5,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
9,Razorbill,12,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
10,Red-billed_Chough,3,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
11,Willow_Warbler,10,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
12,Northern_Wheatear,12,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
13,Reed_Bunting,2,23-Apr-14,Harry_Hops,"Skomer_Island,_Pembrokeshire_County",-5.30310871,51.73776583
14,Barn_Swallow,2,14-Apr-14,Paul_Owen,"WhiteHill,_Pembrokeshire_County",-4.819516968,51.71073247
15,Common_Chiffchaff,2,14-Apr-14,Paul_Owen,"WhiteHill,_Pembrokeshire_County",-4.819516968,51.71073247
16,European_Goldfinch,4,14-Apr-14,Paul_Owen,"WhiteHill,_Pembrokeshire_County",-4.819516968,51.71073247
17,Common_Merganser,4,12-Apr-14,Howard_Williams,"Bute_Park,_Cardiff,_Cardiff_County",-3.185524062,51.48431536
18,Great_Crested_Grebe,2,12-Apr-14,Howard_Williams,"Cardiff_Bay_Harbour,_Cardiff_County",-3.168233956,51.45798394
19,Barn_Owl,1,07-Apr-14,Toby_Rowland,"Carmel,_Carmarthenshire_County",-4.045078962,51.82685504
20,Carrion_Crow,1,05-Apr-14,Toby_Rowland,"Aberaeron_harbour,_Ceredigion_County",-4.263096052,52.24298592
21,Bar-headed_Goose,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
22,Gadwall,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
23,Eurasian_Wigeon,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
24,Northern_Pintail,2,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
25,Common_Buzzard,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
26,Little_Ringed_Plover,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
27,Spotted_Redshank,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
28,Common_Greenshank,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Newport_Wetlands_RSPB_Reserve,_Newport_County",-2.963961861,51.5462345
29,Common_Snipe,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Kenfig_NNR,_Bridgend_County",-3.731128585,51.51604494
30,Great_Spotted_Woodpecker,1,05-Apr-14,Simon_Priestnall,"Fendrod_Lake,_Swansea_County",-3.903193858,51.66903139
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Add Delimited Text` form only lists the first 20 data rows.

After loading, you see the rest in the attribute table as well:

[image]

By the way, I'm pretty sure you swapped lat and lon values. Your data shows up east of Africa, instead of South Wales as the `LOCATION` field suggests.

Comment: The lat/lon swap is a classic, I remember really scratching my head the first time I ran into that.